# Error stargazer in R script multiple regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, rscript

I am new to R and trying to make this script to work. I´m attempting to do multiple regression for `Y=dag, X1=OP, X2=NOKUSD` etc. with dummy-variables (a,b,c..). This is my script:

```
library(tokenizers)
library(corpus)
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr) 
data1 <- read.xlsx("Kladding2.xlsx")
head(data1)
lm(dag~OP,data=data1) 
library(stargazer)
m4 <- lm(dag~OP+NOKUSD+APR+OSEBX,data=data1)
library(corrplot)
stargazer(m4, title="data2", align=TRUE,
          no.space=TRUE,type="text") 
m5 <- lm(dag~OP+NOKUSD+APR+OSEBX+a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z+aa+ab+ac+ad+ae+af+ag+ah+ai+aj+ak+al+am+an+ao+ap,data=data1)
stargazer(m5, title="data2", align=TRUE,
          no.space=TRUE,type="text")
```

When I enter this script, the following error appears:

```
stargazer(m5, title="data2", align=TRUE,
+           no.space=TRUE,type="text") 
Error in stargazer(m5, title = "data2", align = TRUE, no.space = TRUE,  : 
  could not find function "stargazer"
```

I have already downloaded the package called stargazer.

Comment: Either you did not run ```library(stargazer)```, or you need to install this package first (```install.packages("stargazer")```) before loading it

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried to install the package, but this error appear:> install.packages("stargazer")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/stargazer_5.2.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 621898 bytes (607 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 607 KB

Comment: this is not an error message, or you did not put the full messsage in your comment. Once ```install.packages``` is over, try ```library(stargazer)```